# how to using native UI when developed UI in android?

Tags: android, user-interface

Does anyone know how to use the custom UI which phone manufacturer uses for android their Android phone?

For example when the app runs on Samsung phone, it show touch wiz UI, when running on a HTC phone, it appear to be Sense UI (like a native application specific to that phone)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't get the question. In general, if you do not customize your UI all the components (TextView, EditText, Button, etc) will use the styling of the "skin" (Sense, TouchWiz, etc). So presumably the answer to your question is: you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Some vendors such as HTC and Samsung provide additional APIs. Those APIs may provide access to vendor-specific UI. I think you can use those APIs when developing with Eclipse by installing them via SDK Manager. I didn't have a chance to use any of it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. What you see in vendors phones such as Samsung or HTC, it's theirs custom build components. Some vendors provides access to their libs, but your app for Samsung will have strange view on HTC, and not all components are available.

I think, it's better to create your own component with configurable view, for platform you like. I did so, for bottom sliding tabs, as in HTC Clock app.

Comment: Probably if one determines at runtime on which phone the app runs she then will be able to use this or that custom package. I agree though that's maybe not worth it, a more simple approach would be to develop 1 version for Samsung another one for HTC At the same time I believe 3rd party components would be, in general, prettier than those made by deveopers themselves